# Command line script interacting with GUI program

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to build a command line script to automate a process. Most of the script is straight forward, but there is one part where I need to convert a file from one format to another.

Unfortunately, the starting format is propriety and only one Windows software program supports this file type, and that program is only controllable via a GUI.

What I need to do in the GUI is simple:

- open the program (if it is not already open)
- file > open > [file]
- (let file fully load)
- file > export> xml > uncompressed > export > [give name] > save
- (wait until finished)
- (proceed)

Is there a way to work a GUI program into a command line script? How would I start? Would I need a dedicated computer that no one uses for this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to power a GUI program from a script: [autohotkey (AHK)](https://autohotkey.com/). In short - though this summary trivializes its power - think of AHK as a way to send keyboard shortcuts to Windows and the program:

- <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Windows Run... dialog
- Type: `program` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Seize Window of program
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open File menu
- etc...

So, you write an AHK script to do the Windows interaction, and you invoke autohotkey with that .ahk file as part of your pipeline.

As for needing a dedicated computer? I'd recommend it. But, if you have just one metal box, spin yourself up a VM and run your pipeline inside of that -- that leaves the primary OS available for interaction, while the VM does the load lifting.